# Fixing DoExpressCheckout error 10422 in production

Tags: paypal

In production, DoExpressCheckout is returning PayPal error 10422 'The customer must return to PayPal to select new funding sources'.

What docs I've found from PayPal are limited (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#id09C3F05600A)

> Instruct the customer to use a different funding source. Offer the customer a quick link to restart the Express Checkout flow and redirect the customer back to PayPal.

I'm trying to figure out what this means since I personally have no way of regenerating the error and so have no way of testing my code (and asking my exasperated customer to do a couple walkthrus while I sort out the kinks seems unreasonable).

Does anyone know

- references for causes of this error?
- How to generate this error myself to walkthrough for customer experience?
- What redirect should be used? (the first paypal.com...?token= url or should I now be including PayerID?).

All comments solicited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Paypal is instructing you to start the Express Checkout process over on YOUR site (as in generate a new token).

Yes, their error codes leave much to be desired

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with the funding method the person chose while on the PayPal pages.  Maybe they chose to pay with a bank account that isn't verified and your system wont' accept that, for example.

Is this a customer telling you they're getting this error, I'm guessing..?  I would ask them what type of payment source they're choosing and see if anything jumps out about what could be wrong.

Comment: I found the error in my server logs. The customer admitted having no problems using the same funding method to purchase elsewhere. I haven't disabled accepting payments of any type (and was dismayed the first time I saw that my integration accepted an 'eCheque' as payment, something that wasn't guaranteed to clear ...). Do you have references for how an account may be configured to disallow particular payment options?

Comment: If you want to disable the e-checks you can do that from within your PayPal profile.  It's under Payment Receiving Preferences or something like that.  That said, if somebody wants to pay that way you could lose the sale.  If you setup IPN you can automate the processing of handling orders with pending payments correct.  If it's a digital goods order of some sort, or a subscription signup, you can have the system update only when their payment has indeed cleared.